# count of specific directories in a subtree with bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, find

So, I have a directory tree that should be in the following format:

```
 ~/root/dir.abc/
 ~/root/dir.adc/
```

And I want to make sure both directories are present

I have tried

```
 find ~/root -type d -regex "\S*\.a(b|d)c"
```

To do this but to no avail.  How would I go about doing this?

Doing

```
 find ~/root -type d -name *.abc
 find ~/root -type d -name *.adc
```

Can give me what I want with some addition stuff thrown in there, but I just want to narrow it down to one line if possible.

Comment: Why are you using `\S` there are not spaces? Also find doesn't support pcre anyway, Also the regex has to match the entire path, maybe try something like  `-regex '.*/dir\.a[bd]c'`

Comment: `\.a[bd]c` should be all you need.

Comment: @sln with what flag?

Comment: Try `-regextype posix-extended -regex '\.a[bd]c'`

Comment: @sln That won't work since regex matches full path.

Comment: @123 - Can't you add `.*` before and after ??

Comment: @Sln yeah you could do it like i showed above or probably a better way since it is simple would to be to just use name like `-name 'dir\.a[bd]c'` or if they wanted anything in the string with `a[bd]c`, `-name '*\.a[bd]c'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`find`** solution:

```
find ~/root -type d -path "*/dir.a[bd]c"
```

Comment: This is it. Thanks.